# Frida syntax fo variadic print function

Tags: frida

With Frida's Objective-C API ( written in Javascript ), I can:

```
var b = ObjC.classes.NSString.stringWithString_("foo");
    
b.isKindOfClass_(ObjC.classes.NSString)
1  // true
    
b.isKindOfClass_(ObjC.classes.NSUUID)
0  // false
    
b.isEqualToString_("foo")
1
    
b.description().toString()
"foo"
```

But I can't find the correct syntax for a `variadic` `NSString init` call like this:

```
var c = ObjC.classes.NSString.stringWithFormat_('foo', 'bar', 'lives', '...');

c.description().toString()
"foo"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The below did the trick:

```
var c = ObjC.classes.NSString.stringWithFormat_('foo ' + 'bar ' + 'lives');

c.description().toString()
"foo bar lives"

console.log(c)
foo bar lives
```